# How add custom event in extjs 6?

Tags: extjs6, custom-events

I'm usign [Extjs 6](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0). I extended a class from `Ext.Component`. I want to add the class some events.

**How can I do it**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to declare custom events in ExtJS 6. You simply need to listen to them and fire them.

```
component.fireEvent("customEvent", component, otherArgs);
```